# PHPExcel append values to data in next available columns

Tags: php, phpexcel

How would I go about appending data to the end of a row on the next cell within a sheet that has already had data imported.

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( 'CSV' )->setDelimiter( ',' )->setEnclosure( '"' )->setLineEnding( "\r\n" )->setSheetIndex( 0 );
$reader->setSheetIndex( $sheet_index );
$reader->loadIntoExisting( $input_dir . $file , $excel );
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle( $title_parts );

return $excel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the highest row/column values in the loaded worksheet using the $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow() and $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() methods, then adjust those to get the cell you want to set new data in